# What is the correct URL for Google's Cloud Speech API internet requests and how to request using java?

Tags: java, api, key, google-cloud-speech

I'm simply using Eclipse IDE and Java to try to collect voice memos through a microphone, then turn that audio into text in real time. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right but if I send this URL the compiler give me a 403 error meaning it doesn't accept the key that I paste onto the URL. So my question is: 
Does anyone happen to know why the URL connection is not taking my key? or which application restriction should I be using instead of NONE?

```
public class Recognizer {

    /**
     * URL to POST audio data and retrieve results
     */
    private static final 
    String GOOGLE_RECOGNIZER_URL_NO_LANG 
    = "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?lang=en- 
    us&key=InsertMyKey&output=json";
    . . . 
    . . . 
    . . . 
    private String rawRequest(byte[] bytes, String language) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("in this second construct" );
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConn;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    BufferedReader br;

    // URL of Remote Script.
    url = new URL(GOOGLE_RECOGNIZER_URL_NO_LANG);

    // Open New URL connection channel.
    urlConn = url.openConnection();

    // we want to do output.
    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);

    // No caching
    urlConn.setUseCaches(false);

    // Specify the header content type.
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac; rate=8000");

    // Send POST output.
    outputStream = urlConn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(bytes);
    outputStream.close();

    // Get response data.
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

    String response = br.readLine();

    br.close();

    return response;

}
```

[picture of my key settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geSaj.png)

Comment: can you consider to use SpeechClient
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/speech/v1/SpeechClient.html

Answer (score 0):

This API endpoint release seems to be offered only for the community developers of the **Chromium project**; however, it is **NOT** possible to get additional quota, as mentioned in [this documentation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).

Instead, it is required to use the official [v1](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize) or [v1p1beta1](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/speech/recognize) endpoints to perform you speech recognition tasks. Additionally, I recommend you to take a look on the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) guides in order to get detailed information about the process to use Speech-to-Text API service by using programming languages, including **Java**.